# NSNetService's "stop" method not working

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, methods, nsnetservice

I'm using NSNetService to broadcast using Bonjour. But when I want to stop it I use `[netService stop]`, where `netService` is my `NSNetService`. It just doesn't stops, it gets called, but doesn't stops. `netServiceDidStop` is not being called, so I guess somehow I can't stop it. BTW this project uses Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), which I suspect is the reason of this problem. What's wromg?

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure this out? I'm seeing the same thing.  But the sample code for SimpleNetworking does not exhibit this.  In my case, I'm just testing publishing and stopping the Bonjour offering.  I have not yet opened any streams, which is maybe where the problem is coming in.  More fully, I have BonjourBrowser.app running on my Mac, and when I start my NSNetService on my iOS device, the Bonjour registration shows up in BonjourBrowser.  When I stop the NSNetService and remove it from the run loop, BonjourBrowser still shows the registration, even after using that app's "Reload Services" button.  By contrast, SimpleNetworking disappears from BonjourBrowser as soon as you stop it's server service.  And, interestingly, SimpleNetworking doesn't remove the service from the run loop (at least not explicitly).

I was suspecting my TimeCapsule was doing Bonjour sleep proxying, but I rebooted it and BonjourBrowser never showed my service going away.